# How to create a flexible frame for photo in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, frame, photo, setneedsdisplay

I try to create a flexible frame for in my iPhone app with some small pictures. CustomView inherit UIView and override it's `setFrame:` method. In setFrame:, I try to call `[self setNeedsDisplay];` Every time I scale the photo, this frame really display and changed, but something does not work very well. Code and effect below:

[image: This is the image that I used to draw the frame, in code for self.patternImage]

---

[image: Effect of my code]

---

[image: Effect of my code]

---

//rotate to get mirror image of originImage, and isHorization means the rotation direction
    - (UIImage*)fetchMirrorImage:(UIImage*)originImage direction:(BOOL)isHorization{
        CGSize imageSize = originImage.size;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

```
    if (isHorization) {
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
    }else {
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
    }

    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -imageSize.height);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height), originImage.CGImage);
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}

- (UIImage*)fetchPattern:(PatternType)pattern{
    if (!self.patternImage) {
        return nil; 
    }

    UIImage *tmpPattern = nil;
    CGRect fetchRect = CGRectZero;
    CGSize imageSize = self.patternImage.size;
    switch (pattern) {
        case kTopPattern:
            fetchRect = CGRectMake(self.insetSize.width, 0, imageSize.width-self.insetSize.width, self.insetSize.height);
            tmpPattern = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.patternImage.CGImage, fetchRect)];
            break;
        case kTopRightPattern:
            fetchRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.insetSize.width, self.insetSize.height);
            tmpPattern = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.patternImage.CGImage, fetchRect)];

            break;
        case kRightPattern:

            break;
        case kRightBottomPattern:

            break;
        case kBottomPattern:

            break;
        case kLeftBottomPattern:

            break;
        case kLeftPattern:
            fetchRect = CGRectMake(0, self.insetSize.height, self.insetSize.width, imageSize.height-self.insetSize.height);
            tmpPattern = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.patternImage.CGImage, fetchRect)];
            break;
        case kLeftTopPattern:
            fetchRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.insetSize.width, self.insetSize.height);
            tmpPattern = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.patternImage.CGImage, fetchRect)];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return tmpPattern;
}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (self.patternImage == nil) {
        return;
    }

    // Drawing code.
    UIImage *conLeftImage = [self fetchPattern:kLeftTopPattern];
    [conLeftImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    UIImage *topImage = [self fetchPattern:kTopPattern];
    [topImage drawAsPatternInRect:CGRectMake(self.insetSize.width, 0, self.frame.size.width-self.insetSize.width*2, self.insetSize.height)];

    UIImage *leftImage = [self fetchPattern:kLeftPattern];
    [leftImage drawAsPatternInRect:CGRectMake(0, self.insetSize.height, self.insetSize.width, self.frame.size.height-self.insetSize.height*2)];

    UIImage *conRightImage = [self fetchMirrorImage:conLeftImage direction:YES];
    [conRightImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-self.insetSize.width, 0)];

    UIImage *rightImage = [self fetchMirrorImage:leftImage direction:YES];
    CGRect rectRight = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width-self.insetSize.width, self.insetSize.height, self.insetSize.width, self.frame.size.height-self.insetSize.height*2);
    [rightImage drawAsPatternInRect:rectRight];

    UIImage *botRightImage = [self fetchMirrorImage:conRightImage direction:NO];
    [botRightImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-self.insetSize.width, self.frame.size.height-self.insetSize.height)];

    UIImage *bottomImage = [self fetchMirrorImage:topImage direction:NO];
    CGRect bottomRect = CGRectMake(self.insetSize.width, self.frame.size.height-self.insetSize.height, self.frame.size.width-self.insetSize.width*2, self.insetSize.height);
    [bottomImage drawAsPatternInRect:bottomRect];

    UIImage *botLeftImage = [self fetchMirrorImage:conLeftImage direction:NO];
    [botLeftImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height-self.insetSize.height)];

    [super drawRect:rect];
}

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    [super setFrame:frame];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, I make it!!![image: final effect]
The only thing I need to do is set the phase of current context.

```
CGContextSetPatternPhase(context, CGSizeMake(x, y));
```

x, y are the start point where I want the pattern to be drawn.

I just made a mistake to use pattern. If I don't set the phase of current context, It start fill the pattern from the left top of context(0,0) every time.

```
        CGColorRef color = NULL;
    UIImage *leftImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"like_left.png"];
    color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:leftImage].CGColor;
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, FRAME_WIDTH, rect.size.height));

    UIImage *topImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"like_top.png"];
    color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:topImage].CGColor;
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width,FRAME_WIDTH));

    UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"like_bom.png"];
    CGContextSetPatternPhase(context, CGSizeMake(0, rect.size.height - FRAME_WIDTH));
    color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:bottomImage].CGColor;
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, rect.size.height - FRAME_WIDTH, rect.size.width, FRAME_WIDTH));

    UIImage *rightImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"like_right.png"];
    CGContextSetPatternPhase(context, CGSizeMake(rect.size.width - FRAME_WIDTH, 0));
    color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:rightImage].CGColor;
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(rect.size.width - FRAME_WIDTH, 0, FRAME_WIDTH, rect.size.height));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll say this:
I don't have a real answer right now. But, I have a hint .. I think it'll be useful.

According to the [tutorial posted by Larmarche](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-transparent-uiviews-rounded.html), you can customize the borders of a UIView easily by overriding `drawRect:`. And, if you scroll down to the comments below (in the tutorial website), you can see the following comment:

> I discovered one other glitch. When you change the RoundRect's bounds,
>   it will not be updated -- so the **corners** sometimes get all **screwy**
>   (because they're scaled automatically).
>
> The quick fix is to add the following to both init methods:
>
> `self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;`

Setting the contentMode to Redraw saves you the trouble of calling `setNeedsDisplay`. You can easily change the frame of the UIView, instantly or animate it, and the UIView will redraw automatically..

I will try to take a better look at your problem later .. I'll try to actually implement it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried contentMode just now, but it still don't work.

Comment: Yeah, I have put the code above. I just override drawRect, and the images are the result that I got.